# Can python's math.ceil function get tricked from floating point representation error?

Tags: python, floating-point, ceil

The question is in the title, for example what I am worried about is:

If I calculate `math.ceil(math.log(4,2))`, do I have the risk of getting 3 instead of 2 because the log will return 2.0000000000000343 instead of 2.0?

I suspect not but I haven't found something to confirm it!

Comment: You may want to look at `int.bit_length()`: for a positive integer `n`, `math.ceil(math.log(n, 2))` is more safely computed as `(n-1).bit_length()`. Also, note that recent versions of Python have `math.log2`, which is a bit more accurate than `math.log(..., 2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can simply calculate `math.ceil(math.log(x**y,x))` for many `(x,y)` pairs until it isn't equal to `y` :

```
>>> next((x,y) for x in range(2,100) for y in range(2,100) if y != math.ceil(math.log(x**y,x)))
(2, 29)
>>> '%.30f' % math.log(2**29,2)
'29.000000000000003552713678800501'
>>> math.ceil(math.log(2**29,2))
30.0
```

To avoid this problem, you could simply use [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) instead of `math.ceil`.

`(2,29)` is just the first pair of many problematic ones:

```
[(2, 29), (2, 31), (2, 39), (2, 47), (2, 51), (2, 55), (2, 58), (2, 59), (2, 62), (2, 93), (4, 29), (4, 31), (4, 93), (5, 3), (5, 6), (5, 12), (5, 13), (5, 17), (5, 21), ...
```